# Выполняет ли Access оптимизацию запросов?

Tags: sql, access, office

Например, будет ли преобразован LIKE 'Вася' в ='Вася'?
Или преобразует ли он IN в JOIN, если используется первичный ключ ?

Понятное дело, что Access во много слабее MS SQL, но интересно, а что он может оптимизировать, а что нет.

Answer (score 2):

Да, некоторую оптимизацию Акцесс, конечно, делает. Что конкретно меняется можно косвенно посмотреть по плану выполнения. Как включить логирование плана описано [здесь](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388/). К сожалению, план очень бедный и много не увидишь, но можно хотя бы увидеть, что он меняется, например, при добавлении wildcards в like.

В дополнение к статье вот некоторые ключи для разных вариантов системы:

For Acess 2007+ registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Debug

32 bit on 64 bit system:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Debug